unionByName is only using a single core in apache spark
This has been driving me a little crazy so any help is greatly appreciated
I have a list of dataframes df_list with maybe around 500 small dataframes (I ingested csvs and wrote them as parquets, then I read each one as a spark df and appent to list)
and I'm trying to merge them like this
merged_df = reduce(lambda left, right: left.unionByName(right, allowMissingColumns=True), df_list)

the problem is this is only using a single core, and is bottlenecked, I don't understand why my other cores aren't being activated (I'm viewing htop)
I also tried this
df_list = [df.repartition(16) for df in df_list]  # Adjust the number based on your cluster size
merged_df = df_list[0]
for df in df_list[1:]:
    merged_df = merged_df.unionByName(df, allowMissingColumns=True)

no luck. How can I get more core activation? How can I get spark to distribute this merge accross multiple cores/executors? Does this question even make sense and if not, what am I fundamentally misunderstanding here?
I have a 128 gb memory, 32 core ec2 instance.
Below is the environment, basically I have a spark master and 1 worker (with 5 executors, each 4 core, 16 gb ram) running on a single ubuntu machine, I'm running this from a jupyter notebook and initializing my spark client as such
spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("spark://<removed by me>:9077")
    .appName("spark_experiment_mark_21")
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "16g")
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors", 5)
    .config("spark.executor.cores", 4)
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "30g")
    .config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled", True)
    .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","10g")
    .getOrCreate()
)

I believe most of the values are taking, I can see them in the spark configuration, also I set the following environment
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=20
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=80g

and the following spark properties (perhaps redundantly
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors        5
spark.executor.memory                           16g
spark.executor.cores                            4
spark.memory.offHeap.enabled                    true
spark.memory.offHeap.size                       20g

the spark.memory.offHeap.size I set in the spark session object is overriding the one in the properties file

Do you need to read them into separate dataframes? You can read all csv or parquet file together into a single dataframe. That should help with distribution of data over nodes.

Spark distributes tasks at the partition level, but the way you've implemented the merging process may inherently limit parallelism.
you can do

Repartition Before Merging

Use unionByName in a Parallel-Friendly Way
def parallel_union(dataframes):

 while len(dataframes) > 1:
     # Pairwise union of DataFrames
     dataframes = [
         dataframes[i].unionByName(dataframes[i + 1], allowMissingColumns=True)
         for i in range(0, len(dataframes) - 1, 2)
     ] + ([dataframes[-1]] if len(dataframes) % 2 == 1 else [])
 return dataframes[0]

merged_df = parallel_union(df_list)




The question does not make sense, and although I get your point, the reality is:

reduce is serial , and
UnionByName is also a a serial operation in terms of (py)Spark.

You would need to roll your own code/logic, somehow.
